# Jolt to check non-null value and then add a new field

Tags: json, transform, jolt

Below is the json input file.

```
{
  "data": {
    "no1": 12345,
    "cp1": {
      "cp1_sub1": "sub1",
      "cp2_sub2": "sub2"
    },
    "cp2": null
  }
}
```

the expectation is like adding a "no1" field inside the "cp1" and "cp2" if it is non-null object.

I have tried with following 2 ways but non of it is working. Is there any way to check null or add a null value with a new key in jolt?

Try 1:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": "data.&",
        "cp1": {
          "@(1,no1)": "data.cp1.no1",
          "*": "data.cp1.&"
        },
        "cp2": {
          "@(1,no1)": "data.cp2.no1",
          "*": "data.cp2.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here the problem is it adds "no1" in "cp2".

Try 2:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": "data.&",
        "cp1": {
          "@(1,no1)": "data.cp1.no1",
          "*": "data.cp1.&"
        },
        "cp2": {
          "*": {
            "@(1,no1)": "data.cp2.no1",
            "*": "data.cp2.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here the problem is "cp2" it self removed. If this is correct then how we can add back `"cp2": null`

---

If the input is an array like this.

```
{
  "abc": "def",
  "data": [
    {
      "no1": 12345,
      "cp1": {
        "cp1_sub1": "sub1",
        "cp2_sub2": "sub2"
      },
      "cp2": null
    },
    {
      "no1": 56789,
      "cp1": null,
      "cp2": {
        "cp3_sub1": "sub1",
        "cp3_sub2": "sub2"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried with the same way with @Barbaros answer. but the last step is not working for the array part. Considering cp1 and cp2 as the fixed key and not a dynamic.

```
[
  {
    // multiplex the current JSON value in order to use one for logical comparisons later
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "*": "data.[&1].&",
          "@(0,cp1)": "data.[&1].temp-cp1",
          "@(0,cp2)": "data.[&1].temp-cp2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // determine whether the value of the attribute/object is "null"
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": {
          "temp-cp1": ["=toString", "NuLllLL"],
          "temp-cp2": ["=toString", "NuLllLL"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should generate a comparison identifier in order to be prepared for upcoming conditional which will be held within a consequent transformation

```json
[
  {
   // multiplex the current JSON value in order to use one for logical comparisons later
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "@": "New_&1.&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // determine whether the value of the attribute/object is "null"
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "New_data": {
        "data": {
          "cp*": ["=toString", "NuLllLL"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // use conditional logic based on the results determined within the previous transformation
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "New_data": {
        "data": {
          "cp*": {
            "NuLllLL": {
              "@(4,data.&1)": "&3.&2"
            },
            "*": {
              "@1": "&3.&2.new_&2",
              "@(4,data.no1)": "&3.&2.no1"
            },
            "*}": { // check out if it's an object
              "@(4,data.&1)": "&3.&2",
              "@(4,data.no1)": "&3.&2.no1"
            }
          },
          "*": "&1.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Comment: This is awesome. I am still trying to understand the same after 2 hours. :) If data is an array. data[] then how to handle the same?

Comment: Also, I am not sure but I think if it's a large data array then copying the entire array will be memory intensive.